# How can I write this LC3 program?

Tags: assembly, lc3

Write a LC-3 assembly code to count the number of "1" bits in register R0 and place the result in register R5. For example, if R0 contains "0000 0001 0010 1100" a result of 4 should be stored in R5.  I have a little bit of info I got from various sources but the coding isn't for the right program and I don't understand LC3 enough to adapt it. Here's what I have so far:

```
.ORIG x3000

        AND R5, R5, #0        ; R5 will act as a mask to
        AND R5, R5, #1        ; mask out the uneeded bit
        AND R1, R1, #0        ; zero out the result register
        AND R2, R2, #0        ; R2 will act as a counter

        LD R3, NegSixt        ;
MskLoop     AND R4, R0, R5        ; Mask off the bit
        BRz NotOne        ;

NotOne      ADD R1, R1, #1        ; if the bit is 0 don't increment
        ADD R5, R5, R5        ; shift the mask one bit to the left
        ADD R2, R2, #1        ; Increment counter tells where we are
        ADD R6, R2, R3        ;
        BRn MskLoop           ;
        ADD R6, R2, R3        ;
        BRn MskLoop           ; Not done yet go back and
        HALT                  ; check the other bits
        NegSixt .FILL 000000100101100 ;

.END
```

I tried to modify it a little but I'm sure I just messed it up...

Comment: Your first sentence, "Write a LC-3 assembly code to count the number of "1" bits in register R0 and place the result in register R5", makes this sound like a homework assignment. Is it? (They're not disallowed on SO, I'm just asking.)
Please provide your analysis on how your suggested solution fails.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not familar to LC3. 
But to count the number of bits set, use the effect that right shift register commands move the bits into the carry flag.

here's an algorithm of what you need:

```
bitSet counter = 0
loop:
    if (register == 0) {
       jumpto end
    }
    right shift register
    if carry is set {
        increase bitSet counter
    }
    jumpto loop
end:
```

Comment: LC3 has no shift instruction, so this approach isn't really viable.  See https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece411/mp/LC3b_ISA.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend working from first principles instead of just modifying other code for an entire program.  You pretty easily end up in the place where you have no idea what's going on or why.

The approach here is to look at the number one bit at a time and determine if it is a zero or not-a-zero.  So,

```
 0110         0110         0110         0110
&0001        &0010        &0100        &1000
=====        =====        =====        =====
 0000 == 0    0010 != 0    0100 != 0    0000 == 0
```

You can see that there are two entries where the result is not 0 (and thus should increment our count register).

To generalize it, we can loop

```
for each digit
  if (number & mask != 0)
    increment counter
  move "1" in mask to the left
```

The only "tricky" part here is progressing the mask.  In many architectures you can use a shift instruction, but this does not exist in LC3.  However, a shift to the left is just a multiplication by two, and a multiplication of two is just adding something to itself (seen in the code you pasted).